# Can a property of an allOf item contain a $ref to another allOf items definition?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is `"#/allOf/1/properties/body/properties/foo"` a valid $ref?
As stated [in this article](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#reuse) which explains $ref usage, it looks like it should be.
However both [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) and https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ seem to disagree.

Trying with a plain JSON Pointer it definitely seems to be possible: https://repl.it/repls/WretchedSpiritedMammoth

This is the schema I'm testing with.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
      "$id": "http:/example.org/example.schema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "body"
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
          "$id": "http://example.org/foo.schema.json",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "foo": {
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 1
            },
            "bar": {
              "$ref": "#/allOf/1/properties/body/properties/foo"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: These are the errors im getting:

**jsonschemavalidator.net**

> Error parsing schema
>   Message: Error when resolving schema reference `'#/allOf/1/properties/body/properties/foo'`. 
>   Path `'allOf[1].properties.body.properties.bar'`, line .., position ..

**AJV**:

> can't resolve reference `#/allOf/1/properties/body/properties/foo` from id http://example.org/foo.schema.json"

Comment: Looks valid to me! What errors are you seeing?

Comment: I've updated the question with the error messages as you can't properly format comments

Comment: Strange. I managed to get this to work fine on jsonschemavalidator.net... are you sure you're using the EXACT schema you've included in your question?

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: AHHH OK. The problem is with `$id`. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: let me know if the updated answer helps. If not, please let me know and / or join the JSON Schema slack via the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is mostly right, although you've set an `$id` in a subschema.

> The "$id" keyword defines a URI for the schema, and the base URI that
> other URI references within the schema are resolved against.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-00#section-9.2

By adding an `$id` to a subschema, you've reset the base URI for other URI references, which includes any use of `$ref` within the subschema and its children.

`$ref`

> ...Resolved against the current URI base, it identifies the URI of a
> schema to use.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-00#section-8

By changing your definition of bar to the following, your schema will be valid.

```
"bar": {
  "$ref": "#/properties/foo"
}
```

Further edit as Relequestual requested in his later comment:

It is valid to have an absolute URI as subschema $id, but as noted it resets the base URI.  The restrictions on $id values only apply when using it to create local URI fragment identifiers (if this does not mean anything to you, do not worry about it).

Referencing a property schema from another property schema directly is valid, but the more common best practice is to put such a schema under the "definitions" keyword and have both properties refer to that location.  This is what I would recommend for maximum clarity:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
      "$id": "http:/example.org/example.schema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "body"
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
          "$id": "http://example.org/foo.schema.json",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "foo": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/whateverYouWantToCallIt"
            },
            "bar": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/whateverYouWantToCallIt"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
          ]
        }
      },
      "definitions": {
        "whateverYouWantToCallIt": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I'm really sorry but I'm not sure how much, if any, of my answer is correct. I'm checking this with colleagues and will come back to amend or delete and re-answer, which ever is the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm not writing this "completely merged" schema myself, I'm using [json-schema-ref-parser](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/json-schema-ref-parser/blob/master/docs/ref-parser.md#bundleschema-options-callback) (using these schemas: https://pastebin.com/p2yG0FJH) to dereference the $refs of the last schema. It seems like `bundle` generates the reference wrong.

Comment: It looks like, in this instance, it's not possible for you to dereference your schema. Totally dereferencing is not always possible, due to circular references for example. Why do you need to dereferenced?

Comment: [AJV does not support external $refs](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#combining-schemas-with-ref). It's only possible if you know each schema and add them manually. The service I'm building is dynamic therefore schemas can't be known each time.

Comment: I would bet that it does, just that you're doing it wrong. The author of AJV hangs out on our Slack. I suggest you come chat with him directly to try and resolve this and make sure you're doing it the right way. Slack invite link on the official JSON Schema site.