# What is the correct use of json-schema used with ajv?

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

Good morning,
I have a problem using ajv with a json-schema, when using a $ref to something defined in the same json file. I suspect that the problem is with the use of ids, I would understand more about that.

My files are:

**definitions.json**

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "person":{
            "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
            "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/person.json",
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "name":{"type":"string"},
                "surname":{"type":"string"},
                "email": {"type": "string", "format": "email"},
                "sex":{"$ref": "types.json#/definitions/gender"}},
            "required":["name", "surname", "sex", "email"]
        },
        "member":{
            "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/member.json",
            "allOf":[
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/person"},
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "id":{"type":"integer"},
                        "role":{"$ref": "types.json#/properties/man_role"},
                        "is_expert":{"type":"boolean", "default":false},
                        "is_board":{"type":"boolean", "default": false}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "type":"object",
    "properties": {
        "person": {"$ref": "#/definitions/person"},
        "member": {"$ref": "#/definitions/member"}
    }
}
```

**types.json**

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/types.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "gender":{"enum": ["male", "female"]},
        "man_role":{"enum": ["admin", "supervisor", "clerk", "none"]}
    },
    "properties":{
        "gender":{"$ref": "#/definitions/gender"},
        "man_role": {"$ref": "#/definitions/man_role"}
    }
}
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662513/can-a-property-of-an-allof-item-contain-a-ref-to-another-allof-items-definition) question, but I didn't figure it out how to correct my example.
The error I get is:

> MissingRefError: can't resolve reference #/definitions/person from id http://asite.org/schemas/member.json

The references work if I try with VisualStudio Code, e.g I can create a "member" and it recognizes also the properties of "person".

Can anyone tell me how should write these schemas to make them work with ajv?

The code that generates the error is:

```
import Ajv, {JSONSchemaType, DefinedError} from "ajv"
import {Person, Member} from "./definitions";
import addFormats from "ajv-formats"

const ajv = new Ajv();
addFormats(ajv);
ajv.addMetaSchema(require("../node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-06.json"))

const types = require("../types.json");
const PersonSchema : JSONSchemaType<Person> = require('../definitions.json').definitions.person;
const MemberSchema: JSONSchemaType<Member> = require('../definitions.json').definitions.member;
ajv.addSchema(types);

const isPerson = ajv.compile(PersonSchema);
const isMember = ajv.compile(MemberSchema)
//other stuff, use of isPerson and isMember on example objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, the `$ref` isn't resolving as you expect because of the `$id`. `$ref`s are resolved against the `$id` of the schema. In this case, `{ "$ref": "#/definitions/person" }` is resolved against `"$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/member.json"` resulting in `http://asite.org/schemas/member.json#/definitions/person` which doesn't exist. The solution is to use the `$id` of the person schema rather than a relative path: `{ "$ref": "person.json" }`.

---

As an aside, you might prefer the alternate API for compiling schemas that works better when dealing with bundled schemas like your "definitions.json". You can load the whole file and then compile the individual schemas you want by their `$id`.

```
const ajv = new Ajv();
ajv.addMetaSchema(draft06);
ajv.addSchema(definitions);
ajv.addSchema(types);
const isPerson = ajv.getSchema("http://asite.org/schemas/person.json");
const isMember = ajv.getSchema("http://asite.org/schemas/member.json");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Now the validator works, but the schema not anymore: using vscode I see it can't find "person.json", because it assumes it is another file. Also when generating TypeScript types from the json-schema it doesn't "compile" because of this.
It seems there is an incompatibility between how validator searches for object and how the schema should behave

Comment: `$id` is one of the hardest things to get right in a JSON Schema implementation. AJV gets it right (although even they have outstanding bugs last I checked). It wouldn't surprise me if vscode has bugs in this area. You might have to put each schema in it's own file to avoid that problem.